# Calculating the YOLOv4 coordinates draws the wrong annotations

Tags: python, annotations, bounding-box, yolov4

I've been trying to write the correct annotations for YOLOv4. I am told that the annotations need to be calculated relative to the canvas image. But there is an issue where the bounding box is misplaced.

[image]
[image]

This is my function that calculates the annotations for each logo on a canvas image:

```
def get_annotation_coordinates(canvas_shape, logo_shape):
    x = (logo_width + canvas_width) / 2
    y = (logo_height + canvas_height) / 2

    width = logo_width / canvas_width
    height = logo_height / canvas_height

    return f"{x / canvas_width} {y / canvas_height} {width} {height}"
```

What exactly am I doing wrong? Because obviously my calculations are wrong.

Comment: The lines where you define x and y look wrong. Why do you add the same number twice for y only to then divide by 2?

Comment: @ScienceSnake I fixed that but the x and y are supposed to bet he middle of the object, no? That is why I am dividing them by two.

Comment: Try this as a reference: https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg/blob/ebb2b833879d11bc768bcdc44b158784b93faf9d/libs/yolo_io.py#L31